# How to add extra minutes to time data type while sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I want to add extra 30mins to "daily_attendances.in_time" while counting "delay day". Any idea how to do that?

```
$attendance_list = DB::table('daily_attendances')
        ->join('employees', 'employees.card_id', '=', 'daily_attendances.card_id')
        ->select('daily_attendances.*','employees.basic_salary','employees.start_time','employees.over_time_rate',
            DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( daily_attendances.delay_time ) ) ) AS delay_time'),
            DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( daily_attendances.extra_time ) ) ) AS extra_time'),
            DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( daily_attendances.in_use_time ) ) ) AS duty_time'),
            DB::raw('count(daily_attendances.start_time < daily_attendances.in_time) AS delay_day'),
            DB::raw(DB::raw('count(*) as present_day')))
        ->whereRaw($where)
        ->groupBy('daily_attendances.card_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case we have to use MySQL function called `DATEADD`

Example:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2017-01-15 02:12:19", INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

Output:

```
2017-01-15 02:42:19
```

I have modified your query, Please try it out.

```
$attendance_list = DB::table('daily_attendances')
  ->join('employees', 'employees.card_id', '=', 'daily_attendances.card_id')
  ->select('daily_attendances.*','employees.basic_salary','employees.start_time','employees.over_time_rate',
      DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( daily_attendances.delay_time ) ) ) AS delay_time'),
      DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( daily_attendances.extra_time ) ) ) AS extra_time'),
      DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( daily_attendances.in_use_time ) ) ) AS duty_time'),
      DB::raw('count(DATE_ADD(daily_attendances.start_time, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) < daily_attendances.in_time) AS delay_day'), //change over here
      DB::raw(DB::raw('count(*) as present_day')))
        ->whereRaw($where)
        ->groupBy('daily_attendances.card_id')->get();
```

You can also refer to the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)

Comment: I think should be add time in  daily_attendances.in_time  right! like-> DATE_ADD(daily_attendances.in_time, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)